# Debugging feature activation in SP2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-2016, sharepoint-2019

I have one feature in my solution and when I try to activate the feature using **Install-SPFeature**, I get following error-

> Install-SPFeature : Failed to find the XML file at location
>   '15\Template\Features\SPFeatureDefinition
>   Name=FeatureDefinition\15\077954c2-4663-429b-9b27-70afd873b161\feature.xml'

Feature is already deployed at **\15\TEMPLATE\FEATURES**

Moreover, all the virtual directories points to 14 instead of 15 for SP 2013, and 14 instead of 16 for SP2019.